# Is it possible to have several SOMEIP Headers in one Packet?

Tags: ethernet, automotive, vsomeip

I came across this particular packet [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFGZ3.png) from a pcap while researching SOMEIP. My question is whether you can have several SOMEIP headers embedded within one Packet?

The [SOMEIP Protocol Specification](http://autosar.org/fileadmin/standards/R21-11/FO/AUTOSAR_PRS_SOMEIPProtocol.pdf) gives no indication either way from that I can see.

Looked at the specification, wasn't clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think no, If you are developing Automotive application,
But why you need more header on 1 packet?
What is purpose of that, It gonna be huge waste of resource if one of them not used..

Updated :

```
[PRS_SOMEIP_00140] The header format allows transporting more than one
SOME/IP message in a single UDP packet. The SOME/IP implementation shall identify
the end of a SOME/IP message by means of the SOME/IP length field. Based on the
UDP length field, SOME/IP shall determine if there are additional SOME/IP messages
in the UDP packet. (RS_SOMEIP_00010)
```

Comment: This packet (and several others) came from an industry leading testing tool that was simulating SOME/IP traffic, so I'm assuming it's a valid SOMEIP packet because the tool generated it in a reference example, and Wireshark didn't complain about it. 

> But why you need more header on 1 packet?

I can see why you might want to do this, e.g. making several function calls / requests / responses using the one packet from client to server rather than several individual consecutive packets.

I was really just hoping to check whether this is a case of "yeah, this is valid, for x reason"

Comment: Now I understand you question. The packet you referred here is a "Ethernet Packet" which based on UDP or TCP.  and Yes, it can contain multiple SOME/IP header according to below Spec you can see : [PRS_SOMEIP_00140] d The header format allows transporting more than one
SOME/IP message in a single UDP packet. The SOME/IP implementation shall identify
the end of a SOME/IP message by means of the SOME/IP length field. Based on the
UDP length field, SOME/IP shall determine if there are additional SOME/IP messages
in the UDP packet. c(RS_SOMEIP_00010)

Comment: Thanks, this was clearly in the documentation and I missed it. My apologies! Thank you for your time and support.